# Virtualbox Frequently crash when not active for some time

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox

All,
I recently got an updated laptop from thinkpad to HP, with all the latest hardware, double memory and disk compared to the old laptop. But after used it several days. I found that the VM Virtulbox Manger frequently crash (not responding) if I am not active in Virtulbox for some time. I never encounter this issue before in thinkpad. So I am wondering maybe is there any setting need be improved in the new HP laptop?

Also some info for the software:

- Both use windows 10 pro.
- Virtulbox updated from 5.1.26 to 5.2.14 in new laptop.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

all, Later I got suggestion from colleague to create a new VM in the new Virtualbox(v5.2.14) using my old VM "virtual hard disk file", and then everything back to normal. Seems a compatibility issue with old VM in new Virtualbox.

Hope this helps others in the future.

Zhihong